# How do I get the unsigned-installer warning back?

Tags: windows-10, security

I'm developing an application for Windows and I want to sign it so that my customers don't see the scary warning when they are about to install it. My problem is that I don't see the scary warning on my own computer, so, I can't test whether the signature is working.

How do I get the scary warning in Windows 10? Maybe at some point I dismissed it permanently or changed some setting about installing unsafe software? I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe you have signed it already? Do you have a version that you haven't sign?

Comment: @Darius: I haven't purchased a certificate and I'm pretty sure I haven't signed anything yet.

Comment: You could create your own self-signed certificate, trusted it, and therefore trusting that application. Can you try it on a different computer? Or spin up a VM of Windows 10 and run it there?

Comment: @Darius: yes, I could do that if I wanted to test signing the up (and I might), but I know for a fact right now that the installer is not signed, that in other computers it throws a warning, and I want to get the warning on my own computer as well.